# Odd IndexOutOfRangeException, even when caught

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

Well, I have a public static const of:

```
public static ChatLine[] chatLine = new ChatLine[numChatLines];
```

.

The debug shows me this code (later in the same file):

```
for (int num12 = 0; num12 < numChatLines; num12++)
{
    chatLine[num12] = new ChatLine();
}
```

Upon mousing over each data point, it shows me that num12 is 0 and chatLine is chatLine[0].  Which is very odd, since my public const is as I showed you above...  Any idea why this is happening?

.
.

The full stack trace is below:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=Project1
  StackTrace:
       at Project1.Main.Initialize() in C:\Users\X\My Documents\Project1\Main.cs:line 7590
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at Project1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\X\My Documents\Project1\Program.cs:line 14
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you show all the usages of `chatLine` and `numChatLines`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the length of `chatLine` is zero, `numChatLines` is zero when the array is created. You should create the array after setting `numChatLines`.

Comment: Barely beat me to the punch ;)

Comment: Pretty much has to be it, yeah. `numChatLines` was zero as of when the array declaration was processed.

Comment: @Guffa: if `numChatLines == 0` how could we possibly get into the loop?

Comment: @naveen: Because `numChatLines` is assigned a value some time after the array is created.

Comment: numChatLines was a const of 7 before that in the same file, so unless CSharp doesn't run code in order....

Comment: @cbroughton: If it's a constant then it's evaluated at compile time. Then that line can't produce an array with the length zero, so you have to have some other code somewhere that replaces it with another array.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because *numChatLines* is given a value after

```
public static ChatLine[] chatLine = new ChatLine[numChatLines];
```

.. is initialised, which would give a **0** value.

Try:

```
public static ChatLine[] chatLine;
void main()
{
  /* ... your code ... */
  numChatLines = 12;
  chatLine = new ChatLine[numChatLines];
}
```